# How to use tokens in webforms?

Tags: webforms, tokens

I'm trying to use the [current-page:url] token in a webform hidden field (as the default value) but the submission shows "[current-page:url]" literally. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Drupal version ?

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of hidden field setting.

Comment: the better way to deal with this situation is to use `hook_form_alter()` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.5.x

Answer (score 1):

[token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) is a contributed module and not part of Drupal 8 or webform installation.  You have to install and enable before you can use it.

```
composer require drupal/token
drush en token
```

**NOTE:** Webform is not aware of token directly and does not complain because it thinks are you just inputting text

Comment: I can confirm that the [current-page] token is being provided by the token.module.